# Cannot make max-width work with Bootstrap multi level dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a multi-level Bootstrap dropdown menu as shown in [this bootsnipp](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3).

In my case, the menu items can be quite large in some cases. So I need to set a `max-width` (say, 400px). In addition, I don't want the menu items to be cut so I must use `white-space:` normal too. The problem is that my `max-width` is completely ignored. If I set `width` instead it does work. But I do not want that as I may have menus where the whole menu would fit in much less space than width. That's why I need `max-width` to work rather than width.

Any ideas how can then make such a cascade menu with my needs?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Do you have any code?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to you CSS file.

```
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
    white-space: normal;
    max-width:200px;
}
```

This will set the max width (in this example) of every anchor element to 200px.

If you chosse a size lower than 160px you have to set the min-width of the drowdown-menu class as this has a min-width of 160px.

```
.dropdown-menu {
    min-width:110px;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Martin. Indeed your solution worked perfectly for bootstrap example. Thanks! However, when I try to apply it directly into my *real* code (which uses the mentioned cascade menu) it does NOT work. I cannot see what I am doing different :(    [Here](http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/A2WoV) I have the same the original bootstrap example but with my HTML. See that even if I set `max-width: 500px`, that still does not work :(  Any clues??